# Как распознать шрифт на изображении?

Tags: изображения, шрифты, распознавание-образов

1. Какой шрифт использован на прикрепленной картинке?
2. Каким методом/сервисом такое можно узнать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поиск шрифтов не входит в тематику StackOverflow на русском.

Answer (score 4):

1) Похоже на Plakette Serial Regular
2) Например, [этим](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator)